# Получение данных через отношения Eloquent ORM Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Есть такая схемка БД:
[image: связи таблиц]
Главная таблица для работы - request_purchase. Через нее необходимо получить данные из всех других таблиц.
Сейчас прописала следующие отношения:
Модель RequestPurchase:

```
public function requestPurchaseAccepted()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(RequestPurchaseAccepted::class, 'id_request_accept');
}
```

Модель RequestPurchaseAccepted:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'request_purchase_accepted_products', 'id_request', 'id_product');
}

public function car()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Car::class, 'id_car');
}

public function contactConsignee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class, 'id_consignee');
}

public function contactShipper()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class, 'id_shipper');
}

public function requestPurchase()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RequestPurchase::class, 'id_request_accept');
}
```

Модель Car:

```
public function driver()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Driver::class, 'id_driver');
}

public function requestPurchaseAccepted()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RequestPurchaseAccepted::class, 'id_car');
}
```

Модель Driver:

```
public function car()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Car::class, 'id_driver');
}
```

Модель RequestPurchaseAcceptedProduct:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'id_product');
}

public function requestPurchaseAccepted()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(RequestPurchaseAccepted::class, 'id_request');
}
```

Модель Product:

```
public function requestPurchaseAcceptedProducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RequestPurchaseAcceptedProducts::class, 'id_product');
}
```

Для примера я получаю данные в контроллере следующим образом:

```
$requests = RequestPurchase::with(['requestPurchaseAccepted'])->paginate(20);
```

Каким образом можно получить данные из других таблиц, если мне также необходимо получать данные порционо и без кучи запросов в БД для каждой записи RequestPurchase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызывайте методы у RequestPurchaseAccepted

```
$request = $requests->get(0);
$car = $request->requestPurchaseAccepted->car();
$products = $request->requestPurchaseAccepted->products();
```

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос.

Попробуйте так

```
$car = $request->requestPurchaseAccepted->car();
```

Или так

```
$car = $request->requestPurchaseAccepted->car;
```

Точно не помню. Но вроде нужно вызывать метод.

Requests еще нужно получать с get()

```
$requests = RequestPurchase::with(['requestPurchaseAccepted'])->get()->paginate(20);
```

Погуглите laravel ленивая и жадная загрузка

Пример с загрузкой данных в отношениях

```
$requests = RequestPurchase::with(['requestPurchaseAccepted', 'requestPurchaseAccepted.car'])->get()->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А что дает метод get? И как я понимаю, если я буду вызвать метод car, то для каждой записи он будет посылать новый запрос в бд? Нет ли способа загрузить все разом, как когда используешь отношения в рядом стоящих таблицах?

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Других способов не знаю

Comment: Без метода get данные не получает, но точно не уверен

Comment: Ленивая загрузка посылает новый запрос, а жадная одним запросом

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: `get` завершает запрос и возвращает коллекцию, поэтому он не нужен перед `paginate`,` paginate` само завершает запрос возвращает постраничные данные.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Проблема была как раз в том, чтобы найти пример синтаксиса запроса)

Answer (score 0):

Вся суть в глубоких запросах, удобней всего сделать так. Это будет одним запросом. Можно делать какие угодно условия для любых связей.

```
$requests = RequestPurchase::with([
    'requestPurchaseAccepted' => function ($query) {
        $query->with([
            'products' => function ($query) {
                $query->with([
                    'requestPurchaseAcceptedProducts' => function ($query) {
                        $query->with('product', 'requestPurchaseAccepted');
                    }
                ]);
            },
            'car' => function ($query) {
                $query->with([
                    'driver' => function ($query) {
                        $query->with('car');
                    }, 
                    'requestPurchaseAccepted'
                ]);
            },
            'contactConsignee',
            'contactShipper',
            'requestPurchase'
        ]);
    }
])->paginate(20);
```

Надеюсь помог.

Comment: Просто огромное, человеческое спасибо)

Comment: @АлександраНазарова поставьте галочку и стрелочку вверх если ответ подходит.